# The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_SecAddAppPrincipal', database central admin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, high-trust-app

I have a high trust add in in with the following permissions:

```
  <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">    
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />    
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

With this permission the app has full control on all my webapplications. I have several remote eventreceivers and timer jobs running with this app principal.

I build my context with this code:

```
    private static void ExecuteTimerJobOnSiteCollections(Uri webApplicationUrl, WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity)
    {

        using (var clientContext = SharePointTokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(new Uri("http://localhost"), windowsIdentity))
        {
            try
            {
                var siteCol = clientContext.Site;
                var web = siteCol.RootWeb;
                clientContext.Load(siteCol);
                clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Title);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                TaxonomySession session = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
                TermStore store = session.GetDefaultKeywordsTermStore();
                TermGroupCollection groups = store.Groups;


                clientContext.Load(session, s => s.TermStores);
                clientContext.Load(store, s => s.Groups);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("Connected to termstore");
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException wEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + wEx.Message);
            }
            catch (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException sEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + sEx.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I do an app pool recycle and run this code get I get the followin error in the eventlog and my ULS

> Insufficient SQL database permissions for user 'Name: NT
>   AUTHORITY\IUSR SID: S-1-5-17 ImpersonationLevel: Impersonation' in
>   database 'Content_CentralAdmin' on SQL Server instance 'DEVSQL'.
>   Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
>
> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object
>   'proc_SecAddAppPrincipal', database 'Content_CentralAdmin', schema
>   'dbo'.

When I run this code for a second time the error doesn't occur.